Help for finding relevant answers in this reference request question
Learning Chinese using traditional characters is great because traditional characters respect the rules in the Six Writings (六書).
It might be a little bit late, but it would be more helpful if someone can provide some answers in the dupe target which actually answer the linked question.
In my opinion, that's not an exact duplicate.  The dupe post request external resources for Chinese, while the dupe target showcases those for Mandarin.  Chinese and Mandarin aren't the same thing.  People from taiwan, hong-kong and Macao are quite sensitive about the difference of Chinese and Mandarin.  Take chicken wings as an example, it's called 雞翅膀 in Mandarin, but 雞翼 in Cantonese.  '翼' is a more ancient expression than "翅膀".  Both are Chinese expressions, but 雞翼 is not Mandarin.
My try
Most of the answers in the dupe target refers, unluckily, to resources written in simplified characters, whereas the linked question asks for those in traditional characters.

I tried clicking edu.tw, but the links are dead.
In the answer referring to New Tong Wen Tang (新同文堂), the link for Firefox is actually dead.
Remarks: The content itself shouldn't be browser specific.  For instance, I'm using qutebrowser since I'm a big fan of Vim's keystrokes, but these plugins are incompatible with my browser, and I have to google the site.
In the answer referring to Chinese Learn Online, @Alenanno, who closed the linked question as a dupe, claimed that the courses are taught from Taiwan, but its "About Us" page shows that there're (mainland) Chinese and Canadian tutors.
Finally a site written in traditional characters: Classic Chinese Poetry, but even for native Chinese, ancient Chinese is like a foreign language.  Anyways, there's no denying that classic poetry is a great way to learn Mandarin.  Ironically, cantonese preserves much better the tones (平仄) than Mandarin does, especially the entering tone (入聲).  You may refer to the remarks in my first question on this site to know more.

Some scholars views on traditional and simplified characters
I would like to seize this chance to share Nan Huai-Chin(南懷瑾)'s talk on YouTube (transcript on Facebook), in which he said that simplified characters are for illiterates.  For example, the character '衛' (meaning: to defend; simplified: '卫') as an example.  The simplified '卫' reads like an upright flag ⚑ on the ground, and it's not used in ancient Chinese.
More examples can be found, say, in Dr. Gavin Chiu (趙善軒)'s article:

'進' (meaning: progress) is formed by '⻌' and '佳', meaning "gradually enterring into a good state" (漸入佳境), but its simplified character '进' contains '井', which might connote a Chinese proverb "a frog at the bottom of the well" (井底之蛙).
'東' (meaning: east) "contains the Sun" (東必有日), which "rises from the east" (日出東方).  In the simplified '东', the meaning is lost.

A poem to end this post
Although it's adviced to avoid mixing traditional and simplified characters on Chin.SE, I'm typing this poem with mixed characters.

体殘風骨去，爱国掩良心。
  治學守正字，修身唯採陰。
  Source: A comment to a YouTube video

In the first sentence, '體' (body) is replaced by '体', which doesn't contain '骨' (bone).  The simplified character '体' is handicapped (殘) because it doesn't have the strength of character (風骨).  '愛' (love) is mapped to '爱', which hides (掩) '心' (heart).  In simplified Chinese, the word for "patriotism" (爱国) doesn't have a "good heart" (良心).
In the last sentence, an aoju (拗句) "仄仄仄仄仄，平平平仄平" is used.
Regarding the rhyme group, "十二侵" is used.
Food for thought: You may try to find the hidden meanings of this poem.

Edit in response to @droooze's comment
For the simplified character '卫', it seems that there's no universal consensus for its origin.  Some says it's borrowed from the Japanese katakana 'ヱ', but I personally believe Nan Huai-Chin (南懷瑾)'s explanation about the emergence of this character given the era in which he's born.
For the character '進', it merits another main site question.
For the character '東', the explanation above is, as @droooze says, invalid.  From the ancient writing below, we can see that the character is composed by the Sun (日) with wood (木) in the middle.

從木。官溥說。從日在木中。


木、榑木也。日在木中曰東。在木上曰杲。在木下曰杳。得紅切。九部。  

Source: Shuowen Jiezi (說文解字)

Despite the error, the main point remains the same: the simplified character '东' doesn't reflect "the Sun in the middle of a wood" (日在木中).

Is there a question here? I'm kind of confused by the post.

@user3306356 Is there an answer in the dupe target which answers the linked question?  I'm confused by Alenanno's action.  Btw, when Cantonese speakers in HK refer "Chinese" as an academic subject in schools, we refer to a subject taught in Cantonese, while "Mandarin" is a separate subject, so the distinction between "Mandarin" and "Chinese" is crystal clear.

By studying the tones (平仄) of regulated verses (格律詩), such difference is even more evident.  An extreme and purely theoretical example would be the Lion-Eating Poet in the Stone Den (施氏食獅史).

I am heavily opposed to Simplified Chinese too, but the criticisms presented here are mostly invalid. Please only use real academic material in the fields of linguistics and paleography to back up any character explanations - I can assure you that the "scholars" you quoted have no idea what they're talking about.

@droooze Thanks for your feedback, and upvote (maybe?)  I've checked the origin of the three characters '進', '東' and '衛', and edited my post accordingly.  For the characters '体' and '爱' in the poem, that's an obvious observation.

東 is a picture of a bag and forms a core sound and/or meaning component in characters like 重 童 量 囊. 進 describes the motion of a bird (only moves forward, not backward). The description of 東 is quite important as it has consequences for several other characters - it has nothing to do with “east” (which is a rebus borrowing) or “sun”.

@droooze Thanks again for feedback.  Would you mind providing an answer in my follow-up question on the main site?
